# Cast from char * to int loses precision

Tags: c, casting, compiler-errors

I am reading numbers from a file.When I try to put each number into an double dimensional array it gives me below error.How do I get rid of this message?
My variables:
     FILE *fp;
     char line[80];

**Error:  Cast from char * to int loses precision**

Code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *fp;
        char line[80],*pch;
        int points[1000][10];
        int centroid[1000][10];
        float distance[1000][10];
        int noofpts=0,noofvar=0,noofcentroids=0;
        int i=0,j=0,k;

        fp=fopen("kmeans.dat","r");
        while(fgets(line,80,fp)!=NULL)
        {
                j=0;
                pch=strtok(line,",");
                while(pch!=NULL)
                {
                        points[i][j]=(int)pch;
                        pch=strtok(NULL,",");
                        noofvar++;
                        j++;
                }
                noofpts++;
                i++;
        }
        noofvar=noofvar/noofpts;
        printf("No of points-%d\n",noofpts);
        printf("No of variables-%d\n",noofvar);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code would be a good tool to help locate and fix the error.

Comment: Show us the full code. You seem to be trying to assign a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Hmm... that's a lot of data to put on the stack. Even if you do get it to compiler, it might crash when you run it.

Comment: But for the time being I am taking just 5 points which is 5x2 array.

Comment: So are you trying to convert an int in string notation to an actual int? That cast just reinterprets the bits. It doesn't do a smart conversion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the offending line:

```
points[i][j]=(int)pch;
```

You should replace it with

```
points[i][j]=atoi(pch);
```

[`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) is a function that converts a C string representing an integer number in decimal representation to an `int`.

Comment: worth noting that 'atoi' is in the <cstdlib> library

Answer (score 15):

This error occurs while **compiling** on a `64 bit machine` but may not occur on a `32 bit machine` as there is difference in size for `char*` and `int`.

on **64 bit** `sizeof(char*)` is 8 and `sizeof(int)` is 4

on **32 bit** `sizeof(char*)` is 4 and `sizeof(int)` is 4

Comment: +1, This symptom is what I was looking for. I was building an open source library for 64bit machine and encountered the similar error but wasn't sure.